# How do I prevent getting nan values after binning with KBinsDiscretizer?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, data-science, sklearn-pandas, binning

Before binning, I have already dealt with the nan values in the column.

```
sales_df['built'].unique()
```

> array([1955., 1951., 1933., 1965., 1987., 2001., 1995., 1963., 1960.,
> 2003., 1942., 1977., 1900., 1979., 1994., 1916., 1921., 1969.,
> 1947., 1968., 1985., 1941., 1915., 1909., 1948., 2005., 1929.,
> 1981., 1930., 1904., 1996., 2000., 1984., 2014., 1922., 1959.,
> 1966., 1953., 1950., 1927., 2008., 1991., 1954., 1925., 1989.,
> 1973., 1972., 1986., 1956., 2002., 1992., 1964., 1952., 1961.,
> 2006., 1988., 1939., 1946., 1967., 1975., 1910., 1983., 1978.,
> 1905., 1971., 2010., 1924., 1990., 1914., 1926., 2004., 1962.,
> 1923., 2007., 1976., 1949., 1999., 1980., 1901., 1993., 1920.,
> 1997., 1943., 1957., 1940., 1918., 1928., 1974., 1911., 1936.,
> 1937., 1982., 1908., 1931., 1998., 2013., 1907., 1958., 2012.,
> 1912., 2011., 1917., 1932., 1944., 1902., 2009., 1903., 1970.,
> 2015., 1934., 1938., 1913., 1919., 1906., 1945., 1935.])

After using KBinsDiscretizer as such..

```
# use kbinsdiscretizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import KBinsDiscretizer

def kbin(variables, encoding):
    bin_df = sales_df[variables].copy()
    discretizer = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=8,
                                   encode=encoding,
                                   strategy='quantile')
    sales_df[variables] = pd.DataFrame(discretizer.fit_transform(bin_df), columns=bin_df.columns)
    
ordinal_bin = ['built', 'renovation', 'years_from_last_renovation']
ordinal_binned = kbin(ordinal_bin, 'ordinal')
```

I end up with nan values in the column.

```
sales_df['built'].unique()
```

> array([ 2.,  1.,  3.,  5.,  6.,  0.,  4.,  7., nan])

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I forgot to reset the index of the original DataFrame. When I created a new DataFrame with the results from KBinsDiscretizer, the row indices didn't match up and hence created nan values where that occurs.

Just a simple fix before running KBinsDiscretizer

```
sales_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```